# How to connect to Postgres 13 by user with some database

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I installed

```
postgres=# SELECT version();
                                                            version                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 13.5 (Ubuntu 13.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

and I want to create connection for my project(java, php, what ever) so for that I followed in user guide

```
CREATE ROLE admin WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN CREATEDB CREATEROLE ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '111';
```

and right now faced with that

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 admin     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

So, after that

```
CREATE DATABASE spd_talks;
```

and faced with

```
postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | ru_UA.UTF-8 | ru_UA.UTF-8 | 
 spd_talks | postgres | UTF8     | ru_UA.UTF-8 | ru_UA.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | ru_UA.UTF-8 | ru_UA.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | ru_UA.UTF-8 | ru_UA.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

and provide all grant

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE spd_talks TO admin;
```

then admin was added to Access privileges  column

```
postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | ru_UA.UTF-8 | ru_UA.UTF-8 | 
 spd_talks | postgres | UTF8     | ru_UA.UTF-8 | ru_UA.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | admin=CTc/postgres
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | ru_UA.UTF-8 | ru_UA.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | ru_UA.UTF-8 | ru_UA.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

then I try to connect to spd_talks db by admin user and faced with error

```
ivan@ivan-laptop:~$ psql -U admin spd_talks
psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "admin"
```

the same case when I try to did it by IDE

[image]

what I missed, how to correct create user with db and connect by him?

I changed

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

to

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

in

```
sudo gedit /etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf
```

but still faced

```
ivan@ivan-laptop:~$ psql -U admin -d spd_talks
psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "admin"
```

**UPDATE**

when I changed

local   all             all                                     peer
to
local   all             all                                     md5

I faced with successful connection by console

```
ivan@ivan-laptop:~$ psql -U admin -d spd_talks
Password for user admin: 
psql (13.5 (Ubuntu 13.5-0ubuntu0.21.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

spd_talks=#
```

but still error in ide

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this missundertood by

```
spd_talks=# \conninfo
You are connected to database "spd_talks" as user "admin" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5434".
```

and I don't now why but port is 5443, then I canged it in ide and it works

[image]